# Using markdown in typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, markdown

I'd like to use some kind of markup (preferably markdown) in the doc comments in typescript's `d.ts` files, for example:

```
interface MyProps {
  /**
   * The name of the thing. *Important Note:* bla bla.
   * Default value: `foo`.
   */
  name?: string;
}
```

The VS Code editor seems to respect neither markdown nor HTML tags in documentation texts.

Does the typescript language specify any support for markup already or are there any plans towards that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is any support for markup already available or are there any plans towards that

Not enough requests : https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code?query=markdown

## Update:

The language service provides whatever is inside `/** */` as a JSDoc comment. So as far as it is concerned its just a string. Any UI on top will need to support markdown if it wants to.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Actually my question is more related to the typescript language than to the VS Code editor. If it's just a missing feature in the code editor, I can live with that. But I think the language spec should include a statement about the markup support in d.ts comments. I've updated the question to clarify that.